# Get a lenght of Number in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date

I found a code on the internet how to get length of a number in javascript.

```
var month = '10';

//(1)
 month.toString.length    
// =>  return 1
//(2)
 month.toString().length   
// =>  return 2
```

I knew (2) is right. 
But I couldn't find what's difference between (1), (2).

Can you tell me the difference between (1) and (2)?

Comment: `()` is required to invoke a function. Without that, you're just referencing the function

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length

Comment: @CertainPerformance seems like OP wants to know the difference  between `toString().length` and `toString.length`. Kindly check above link.

Comment: `func.length` actually returns the number of parameter it requires.